# IIS 7 - website works without www, but not with

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, cname-record

I have a personal website that I am hosting at home (using web server 2008) that works without www, but not with.  Can someone PLEASE walk me through setting up CNAME, A, and what not.  I have zero experience setting up iis...

Answer (score 5):

The thing to keep in mind is that www.yourdomain.com and yourdomain.com are two different domain names.  There are 2 things to watch for.

1. For DNS you need to have both a root name (yourdomain.com) and www.  If you're using a DNS server, enter the root node (yourdomain.com) as an A record, and www as a CNAME pointing to your A record.

   If you're testing with your hosts file at c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, then make sure to have 2 entries, one for each.
2. For your website bindings, you either need to leave the Host Header blank so that it works for all domain names for your IP address, or you need to add 2 bindings: one for www and one for without.